# Mongoengine orderby on two field getting error

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have more than 20000 documents in mongo and also added the index on `date` and `version` and I want to order it by these two fields

```
order_by('-date', '-version')
```

but while ordering it throws this error

```
database error: too much data for sort() with no index.  add an index or specify a smaller limit
```

Could you please help me out to resolve the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to execute [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor-explain) command to see if Mongo uses your indexes or not.

Since you are sorting your list by `date` and `version` fields maybe you can consider [Compound Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/) as well, especially [sort_order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#sort-order) part because sort order can matter in determining whether the index can support a sort operation.

Happy coding.